# Definition of regular functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset A^{n}_{K}$ be an algebraic set. A regular function on $X$ is a map $\phi : X \to K$ such that there exists $f \in K[T_1, \ldots, T_n]$ with $\phi(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in X$. This definition here feels a bit of strange. Why don't we just define a regular function to be an element in the polynomial ring? Maybe because we also care about how the function might look outside $X$?

Comment: Because two polynomials may be different but yield the same function in $X$.